# Using CONSTRAINT alogn with FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, constraints, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to understand the difference between creating a `FOREIGN KEY` this way:

```
CREATE TABLE child(
    id_child  INT NOT NULL,  
    id_parent INT 
    FOREIGN KEY(id_parent) REFERENCES parent(id_parent));
```

rather than this one:

```
CREATE TABLE child(
    id_child  INT NOT NULL,  
    id_parent INT 
    CONSTRAINT FK_id_parent FOREIGN KEY(id_parent) REFERENCES parent(id_parent));
```

If I use the first form it will create a `CONSTRAINT` anyway (Innodb indexes, or am I wrong? not so illustrated about indexes). So, what's the need to explicitly declare the `CONSTRAINT` or there's no reason to do it?

Comment: From the looks of the official syntax docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html), `CONSTRAINT` is optional, and only needed if you want to (optionally) name the constraint. From what I remember, the main benefit to naming the constraint is easier management (i.e. easier to drop later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `CONSTRAINT` keyword syntax, we can name the constraint according to our chosen convention, rather than having InnoDB use a system assigned name.

That's the only difference.

(Confusingly, the syntax for dropping the foreign key constraint doesn't allow the `CONSTRAINT` keyword,  we have to `ALTER TABLE ... DROP FOREIGN KEY foo`, where `foo` is the name of the foreign key constraint, whether we assigned the name or InnoDB generated it.)

Yes, InnoDB automatically creates an index to support the foreign key, if a suitable index isn't already available.  If we define an index separately (using `KEY indexname (id_parent)` for example, then the foreign key constraint can have a different name than the index.

Comment: Yeah, is very confusing to have, as i see, 2 elements to do just one thing, index. 
e.g. if i want to `references` a specific value, sould i do it through the `constraint`, i mean, `PK_idUser`, or directly through the column name, `idUser`?

Comment: Creating an `INDEX` just defines an index, it doesn't enforce referential integrity.  In relational database theory, rows (tuples) are "related" to each other by storing a common value in a column in the rows to be related (attribute on tuple).  The `FOREIGN KEY` constraint is a mechanism that prevents some values from being stored in a column. It boils down to saying "you can not store a value in this column *unless* that same value appears in a particular column of some row (usually in another table).

Comment: Column names are just identifiers. We could choose to obfuscate the names, the database wouldn't care ... `FOREIGN KEY (xf54gfjlmmph) REFERENCES flurgl7stump (nj87cldgoop)`. Fortunately, we choose not to be that cruel to ourselves, and follow some conventions that help us make sense of things. A common convention is for a foreign key column to have the same name as the column in the referenced table (that convention breaks down, when a table contains multiple foreign key columns that reference the same column.) Adding a prefix such as "fk_"  on a foreign key column is a less frequent pattern

Comment: Don't confuse/conflate the name (identifier) assigned to the CONSTRAINT with the name assigned to the column. In our shop, the naming convention we use for foreign key constraints (not columns) is FK_thistable_referencedtable  (sometimes adding a role discrimanator), that is, we typically do NOT include the involved column name as part of the constraint name.